# how do I remove "Listing 1" from my lstlistings code?

Tags: listings, numbering, captions

This is my latex code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Figure 3]
      Source |       SS       df       MS              Number of obs =     198
-------------+------------------------------           F(  3,   194) =    0.62
       Model |  2.71676158     3  .905587193           Prob > F      =  0.6030
    Residual |  283.499771   194  1.46133902           R-squared     =  0.0095
-------------+------------------------------           Adj R-squared = -0.0058
       Total |  286.216532   197   1.4528758           Root MSE      =  1.2089

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
squared_re~s |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     locati  |   .0029432   .0148768     0.20   0.843    -.0263978    .0322841
density      |  -.0731895   .1233527    -0.59   0.554    -.3164739    .1700949
strike_price |  -.0157999   .0161732    -0.98   0.330    -.0476978     .016098
       _cons |   1.742112   .7439907     2.34   0.020     .2747632    3.209461
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

It displays "Listing 1: Figure 3" when I compile this. How can I remove this? If this is a rudimentary question, I apologize, but it's quite urgent. Thank you.

Comment: It should be `title=Figure 3`, IIRC

Comment: @egreg: Sorry -- I didn't see your comment before I had written my answer.

Comment: @lockstep Don't worry.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Replace "caption" with "title".

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[title=Figure 3]
      Source |       SS       df       MS              Number of obs =     198
-------------+------------------------------           F(  3,   194) =    0.62
       Model |  2.71676158     3  .905587193           Prob > F      =  0.6030
    Residual |  283.499771   194  1.46133902           R-squared     =  0.0095
-------------+------------------------------           Adj R-squared = -0.0058
       Total |  286.216532   197   1.4528758           Root MSE      =  1.2089

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
squared_re~s |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     locati  |   .0029432   .0148768     0.20   0.843    -.0263978    .0322841
density      |  -.0731895   .1233527    -0.59   0.554    -.3164739    .1700949
strike_price |  -.0157999   .0161732    -0.98   0.330    -.0476978     .016098
       _cons |   1.742112   .7439907     2.34   0.020     .2747632    3.209461
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This messes up with `cref`, the reference number no longer displays correctly